# how to debug Karate in chrome

Tags: debugging, configuration, karate

I am new for Karate and VS Code. I downloaded and added the latest version of Karate (0.9.6) as well as added the Karate Runner of Kirk Slota. The example scenarios are running but I am not able to debug. For instance, when I debug the google.feature, I always have the unreachable page as shown in the print screen below:
[image]

what should I change in launch.json to make it working?

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: see if the instructions here give you some tips: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Karate-Robot-Windows-Install-Guide#debug-mode

Comment: thank you @PeterThomas

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the debugger is working with the following configuration:

```
{
     "type": "karate",
     "name": "Karate (debug): Stanalone",
     "request": "launch",
     "feature": "${command:karateRunner.getDebugFile}",
     "karateOptions": "",
     "karateCli": "${config:karateRunner.karateJar.commandLineArgs} -d"
 }
```